# Mysql get data by year with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to get the data based on year with pagination,if the rows count is less,then search in next year

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user_notifications` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y') = '2019' 
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

if rows count is less than 10,then search by year 2018

Comment: What is your connection type to the database?
PDO? Framework?

Comment: yes,laravel framework

Comment: If there are not sufficient records in 2019 and 2018 to give 10 results, do you then want to search earlier years i.e. 2017, 2016 etc.?

Comment: @Nick yes need to check

Comment: Then I don't think you need a `WHERE` clause at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a `WHERE` clause, to include both 2018 and 2019:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_notifications
WHERE YEAR(created_at) IN (2018, 2019)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your results are sorted by `created_at DESC`, I don't think a `WHERE` clause is necessary at all. If there are insufficient results from 2019, your query will automatically return results from 2018, 2017, 2016 etc. as necessary to get to 10 rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user_notifications` 
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: But if, for some reason, no 2018 records be present but there are earlier years, the OP would not want to return them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that is true - but do we know for sure that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

If I've read it right, this sounds like just a simple ordering exercise

```
  SELECT *
    FROM user_notifications
   WHERE created_at < :input_year + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
ORDER BY created_at DESC
   LIMIT :offset, 10;
```

If you only want to go back one year you can just add another condition

```
  SELECT *
    FROM user_notifications
   WHERE created_at < :input_year + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
     AND created_at >= :input_year - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
ORDER BY created_at DESC
   LIMIT :offset, 10;
```

Not that using a function like `YEAR()` on `created_at` rather than a comparison (<,>=) will prevent the engine from using an index on `created_at`

Answer (score 0):

Use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html

```
SELECT *
FROM user_notifications
WHERE YEAR(created_at) <= $searchYear
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```